# Font substitution with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode, substitution

I have an automatically generated document (using Doxygen) that has
many different Unicode characters for many languages: Hebrew, Japanese, Greek, Arabic and more.

Some parts of text displayed using monospace fonts.

I've tried to use the DejaVu Sans font, which includes most of glyphs but I still
miss some Japanese characters and some characters in the monospace fonts.

Is there any way to tell XeLaTeX to make automatic substitutions if the
font is missing glyphs?

So it would for example use one font as main and if something is missing
would fall back to another font or at least to a non-monospace font
that has the correct glyphs?

Comment: This looks like a direct application of XeTeX's interchar class mechanism. Read more [here](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/xetexref).

Comment: @Andrey can you be more specific, at least I can't find information abut this mechanism in the link your provided.

Comment: It's Chapter 3. I haven't tried it, but the workflow for, say, treating Japanese characters specially looks as follows: you assign non-zero to `\XeTeXinterchartokenstate`; you then use `\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 1 = { \SwitchToJapaneseFont } \XeTeXinterchartoks 1 0 = { \SwitchToDefaultFont }`. For finer control you will want to use `\newXeTeXintercharclass` and `\XeTeXcharclass`. Chapter 3 also has a simple example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Andrey points out, the key is the concept of "interchar tokens". Suppose you have some CJK characters that doesn't appear in the normal font and you want to use another for them; say that the characters are U+4E01 and U+4E02.

Then the following will do:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{<a font>}
\newfontfamily{\JapSubstFont}{<another font with the missing chars>}

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\JapSubst

\XeTeXcharclass"4E01=\JapSubst
\XeTeXcharclass"4E02=\JapSubst

\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \JapSubst = {\begingroup\JapSubstFont}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \JapSubst = {\begingroup\JapSubstFont}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \JapSubst 0 = {\endgroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \JapSubst 255 = {\endgroup}
```

Each time that a character in the `\JapSubst` charclass will be at the start or end of a "word" or be preceded or followed by a "normal" character, it will be typeset in the `\JapSubstFont`.

One can also specify a range:

```
\count255="4E01
\loop\ifnum\count255<"5000
  \XeTeXcharclass\count255=\JapSubst
  \advance\count255 by 1
\repeat
```

Comment: Thanks it may suit you... But is there a way to specify for example a range of Unicode not each character particularly? Because for example for CJK it may be HUGE set?

Comment: Thanks... I hadn't thought about loop. I forgot that LaTeX is Turing complete language :-)

Comment: Note that XeTeX version 0.99996 from TL 2016 has increased the number of character classes to 4096, so the boundary class, here denoted by `255`, should become `4095`.

Comment: @JasonZentz Yes, thanks for the update. On the other hand, there are probably better methods, nowadays.

Comment: Just to confirm that as of 2019, you really do need to change `255` to `4095` as per Jason's comment, otherwise I could not get it to compile.

Comment: @egreg Could you please explain the meaning of `XeTeXinterchartoks` and the `begingroup` and `\endgroup` for both `0` and `4095` because I can't find any explaination on Google... I do have it working from your answer though :)