# Replacing missing characters in ASCII/Latin block

Tags: fonts, fontspec, characters

I'm working with a display font that is missing many common characters, including parenthesis, em-dash, and true ``directional quotes''.

I'd like a straightfoward way to replace these with matching characters set in another font when encountered.  A general "if the primary font is missing this character, use this other font" would work, but I can identify all of the characters I care about.  I do not need change the character; if the missing character is, say "(", it will be ( in the fallback font. I'm only using the font in limited circumstances (\chapter and \section in memoir) which may may the problem easier or harder.  Similarly, all fonts involved are TrueType/OpenType.

[newunicodechar](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) and [ucharclasses](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ucharclasses) seem promising, but the former won't meddle with ASCII characters and the latter only works on entire Unicode blocks.

[XeTeX's interchar class mechanism seems promising](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23049/font-substitution-with-xelatex), and is my plan B. But I'd prefer something a bit more portable, if only between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTex.

Minimal Working Example, relying on the [free Cyberfunk font](http://john-gauthier.ca/#typefaces).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
``Dr. J---/Mr. H---'s (Missing Glyph) Day''

\fontspec{Cyberfunk}``Dr. J---/Mr. H---'s (Missing Glyph) Day''
\end{document}
```

[image]

I can provide a longer, more realistic example of how I'm using it with memoir if that's helpful; but it was a lot longer.

Comment: Making `(` active (which is what `\newunicodechar` would do) is a sure way to break other constructs where `(` is expected to be the regular one. Doing a replacement before passing the titles to the actual macros seems the solution with the least impact.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can set up a token cycle to search for the missing glyphs and replace them with glyphs of an alternate font, here taken as Calibri.

Here, I have taken the liberty of searching for and replacing the following glyphs/strings: `(`, `)`, `‘`, `'`, `/`, `-`, `--`, and `---`.

Note that changing catcodes inside of the token cycle can't be easily accomplished, since the tokens are scanned with the current catcodes before they are executed.  This affects verbatim blocks, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,tokcycle}
\newif\ifemdash
\newif\ifendash
\newcommand\dashtest{\emdashfalse\endashfalse\tcpeek\Q
  \ifx-\Q\tcpop\Q\tcpeek\QQ\ifx-\QQ\tcpop\QQ\emdashtrue\else
  \endashtrue\fi\fi
}
\Characterdirective{%
  \ifx(#1\addcytoks{{\setmainfont{Calibri}(}}\else
  \ifx)#1\addcytoks{{\setmainfont{Calibri})}}\else
  \ifx`#1\addcytoks{{\setmainfont{Calibri}`}}\else
  \ifx'#1\addcytoks{{\setmainfont{Calibri}'}}\else
  \ifx/#1\addcytoks{{\setmainfont{Calibri}/}}\else
  \ifx-#1\dashtest
    \ifemdash\addcytoks{{\setmainfont{Calibri}---}}\else
    \ifendash\addcytoks{{\setmainfont{Calibri}--}}\else
    \addcytoks{{\setmainfont{Calibri}-}}\fi\fi
  \else
  \addcytoks{#1}\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\begin{document}
``Dr. J---/Mr. H---'s (Missing Glyph) Day''

Endash -- and Hyphen -

\setmainfont{Cyberfunk}
\tokencyclexpress
``Dr. J---/Mr. H---'s (Missing Glyph) Day''

Endash -- and Hyphen -
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]

The processed tokens of the cycle are buffered and output at the conclusion of the cycle.  If the token cycle is very large (encompassing the whole document, for example), and one is worried about exceeding an internal buffer size, one can instruct the token cycle to  clear the buffer after each ungrouped `\par`, by adding a `\Macrodirective`, as follows:

```
\Macrodirective{
  \addcytoks{#1}\ifnum\tcdepth=0
    \ifx\par#1\the\cytoks\cytoks{}\fi
  \fi% CLEARS BUFFER ON UNGROUPED \par
}
```

Comment: Verbatim can be partially handled by scantokens the result, as long as there's no dashes inside it.

Comment: @user202729 indeed it can.  Also, if one goes through the effort, the token cycle can change catcodes in the middle of its process, through the use of escape tokens, or with more difficulty, examining the input stream for words like `verbatim`.